# Casear Cipher c program won't accept

Tags: c, algorithm, encryption

Why won't my code accept a string that doesn't contain characters a-z A-Z 0-9?
If were to encrypt this to shift for example "aaaaa[[[[[[",
I get an error. 
I want the code so that it can also accept spaces or anything, and skip those that aren't a-z, A-Z, 0-9.

Why won't my last else statement do the trick?

For example:

```
"a       a" shift 1
```

should be

```
"b       b"
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){

    char word[20];
    int rotx;

    printf("enter string\n");
    scanf("%s", word);

    printf("enter rotations\n");
    scanf("%d", &rotx);

    encrypt(word, rotx);

    return 0;
}

void encrypt (char word[], int rotx){

    int w = strlen(word) - 1;
    int i = 0;

    for ( ; i <= w; i++)
        if ((word[i] + rotx) >= 65 && (word[i] + rotx) <=90)
        {
                word[i] += (rotx);
        }
        else if ((word[i] + rotx) >= 97 && (word[i] + rotx) <=122)
        {
                   word[i] += (rotx);
        }
        else if ((word[i] + rotx) >= 48 && (word[i] +rotx) <= 57)
        {
                word[i] += (rotx);
        }
        else if ((word[i] + rotx) > 90 && (word[i]+rotx) <97)
        {
                word[i] = 64 + (rotx - (90-word[i]));
        }
        else if ((word[i] + rotx) > 122)
        {
                word[i] = 96 + (rotx - (122-word[i]));
        }
        else 
        {
        continue;
        }
}
```

Comment: it would help a great deal if you format  your code.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but I expect you don't know what continue does.

Comment: What do you mean 'I get an error'?  Is it a compile time or a run time error?  What is the error message?  Is there a good reason not to use `'A'` and `'Z'` instead of `65` and `90`?  Ditto for most of the other characters.  Your wrapping code is rococo.  You should probably print the input data (it's a good way of checking that the program got the information you think it did!) and validate the rotation.  How do you rotate the digits by 22 places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I honestly have no idea what you are doing.
Here is a code of what I believe caesar cipher is based on wikipedia I read.
If anybody finds a *non syntactical flaw that is detrimental for demonstrational reasons* let me know.

PS, consider reading "https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle", it will help you (and me) a lot.
PS: if I break the coding style above, it does not make me a hypocrite, I just choose what style suits me best.

Took 5 minutes to code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void encrypt(char *res, char *word, int rot)
{
    int len;
    int i;
    int tmp;

    len = strlen(word);

    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        tmp = word[i] - 'a';
        tmp += rot;
        tmp %= ('z' - 'a');
        res[i] = tmp + 'a';
    }

    res[len] = 0;
}

void decrypt(char *res, char *word, int rot)
{
    int len;
    int i;
    int tmp;

    len = strlen(word);

    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        tmp = word[i] - 'a';
        tmp -= rot;
        tmp %= ('z' - 'a');
        res[i] = tmp + 'a';
    }

    res[len] = 0;
}

int main()
{
    char word[20];
    char result[20];
    char decode[20];
    int rot;

    printf("enter a word: ");
    scanf("%s", word);

    printf("enter rotations: ");
    scanf("%d", &rot);

    encrypt(result, word, rot);    

    printf("result: %s\n", result);

    decrypt(decode, result, rot);

    printf("decode: %s\n", decode);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `scanf()` to get the string as input, it intakes the string, ignoring spaces. So if you input

```
hello world
```

only

```
hello
```

is taken as input by scanf. So use fgets()

Comment: I was going to upvote you, but then you said "Use gets()," and I had to downvote instead.  *No one* should **ever** use that abomination *under any circumstances*.  `fgets()` should be used instead.

Comment: may i know what is the problem with gets?

Comment: It's incredibly unsafe, as it has absolutely no protections against buffer overrun.

Answer (score 1):

Your `scanf()` will not read white spaces, so change it into the following style,

```
scanf("%[^\n]", word);
```

And please don't use `gets()` as it is deprecated and its use is dangerous, especially when your aim is to provide security.

Also you don't need such an elaborate `encrypt()` function, the loop given below is more than sufficient to implement Caesar Cipher,

```
for ( ; i <= w; i++)
  {     
     word[i] +=rotx;
  }
```